# Acer One S 1002 stuck after switch on

Tags: freeze

My Acer One S 1002 got stuck on switching on with a message `preparing for automatic repair'. The 'wait' ring keeps rotating and there no further action on screen. Even if it is switched off and restarted, the same as above repeats.  How to fix this problem ?

Comment: It could mean that your Windows installation is corrupted, and cannot repair itself; you might needs a repair disc, or professional services.

Answer (score -1):

Need to unplug power source and let it run until battery dead. Plug back in and let charge back up completely. 
Restart your computer and see if that helps. I have ACER brand also just different numbers. This is the only thing i could do on my end other than just by a new one. When all else fails, let it run down and recharge to full kick

Comment: This might reset the firmware (provided the firmware does not use a backup battery to preserve its settings), but removing the battery, and then turning the power on would be a lot easier, and not damage the battery. However, this would only fix a problem with the firmware. If the issue is with the OS (Windows), then this would not help.